# Why did Shri Rama worship Shiva in Ramayana eventhough He is god?

Tags: shiva, ramayana, rama

I know that Shri Rama is God , then why did He worship Shiva Linga in Ramayana?

Comment: **brahmamurāri surārcita liṅgaṃ** So its not surprising that Sri Rama worshiped Shiva lingam. All beings worship the Shiva Linga be it Gods, asuras, human beings, siddhas etc.. **siddha surāsura vandita liṅgaṃ**, Shiva Linga reprsents the formless Brahman.

Comment: There is no restriction that a God should not worship another God, For example Hanuman worships Rama. Besides that Sri Rama although incarnation of Vishnu, has to be treated as Human because Vishnu himself  told that he will be born as Human(Rama), in that sense Rama as a human worshipped Siva.

Comment: Because Nirguna aspect is always worshipped by sagunas.

Answer (score -1):

Lord Rama was never mentioned as a god in Ramayana. If you've ever heard Rama as god, it is just because of his godly nature and for his golden era of ruling the kingdom, but not because he is god. The avatar of Rama is human and so, he faces so many difficulties. 
The intention in Lord Rama worshiping Lord Siva is that "god-told" Rama worshiped a god (here it is Siva) when he is in hard situations. It is to impart a faith in god when you are facing hard situations.

Comment: Di you read Yuddha kanda? Brahma approaches Rama and tells him about his divinity. But due to humble nature, Rama rejects those claims. That doesn't make him human. He was god. He claimed himself as human and asks about divinity and detail. Please read Ramayana before answering.